# Stream camera view or scene in Unity3D over local network

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, stream, unity3d-2dtools, unity3d-gui

I want to know 
**How can I stream camera view of the player over local network for example HTTP Server or RTSP ?**
because I need to make processing in a python script using OpenCV .

Comment: You could e.g. use a UDP stream?

Comment: How can I use UDP stream ?